# Python: Distinguish if GET (Method-Dispatcher) was called by AJAX or not

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, method-dispatch

i'm stuck with the problem that i can't distinguish between the same overload method GET.
i'm using a Method-Dispatcher so i only have GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods.

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def GET(self, id):
  return str(id)

def GET(self):
  self.db.load_fx()
  ...
```

the ajax is as always

```
function getStudiengang(id){
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "/studiengang/"+id,
      type: "GET",
      data: "",
      success : function(response){
        alert(response);
      }
    })
}
```

the GET-method is called everytime i refresh the webpage, but i also want to call this method with ajax

another solution would be (of course it's not working yet)

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def GET(self, id):
  return str(id)

def default(self):
  return "ok"

def index(self):
  return "nein"
```

Comment: Almost all libraries send an `X-Requested-With` header with value `XMLHttpRequest`, so you can use it to detect whether the request was an ajax request... but it is not 100% guaranteed

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: thank you for your answer but if i send an ajax form the X-Requested-With is XMLHttpRequest, so i can't distinguish it this way

also, i'm not allowed to use another framework